# What is the shortcut on Mac for the Query Tool in PgAdmin4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am trying to find the shortcut for Mac to open a blank page to write a query but it seems is just available for Windows on the PgAdmin4 page.

https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/keyboard_shortcuts.html

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the Mac version of `Alt+Shift` as shown here [Mac Keyboard Shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)?

Comment: That worked! I do not know how I skipped that. Thank you, Adrian!